# Representation of numbers in the computer

Tags: binary, numbers, ascii, representation

In the representation of inputs in the computer, the numbers are taken as characters and encoded with Ascii code or are they converted directly to binary? in other way: When my input is considered as integer and not a character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible, and it depends on the application. In other words the software programmer decides. In general, binary representation is more efficient in terms of storage requirements and processing speed. Therefore binary representation is more usual, but there are good examples when it is better to keep numbers as strings:

- to avoid problems with conversions
- phone numbers
- when no adequate binary representation is available (e.g. 100 digits of pi)
- numbers where no processing takes places
- to be continued ...

Comment: Okay thank you @bogl that answer a part of my question, i undertand now when it's better to use characters but still not clear what my processor will encode my imput, i guess i should ask about the invers, how does it decode, how it knows if the 110000 is the character '0' or the number 48, 1100001 is the character 'a' or the number 97?

Comment: The processor has no clue about it. It will process everything as a number. Assume there is the number 97 stored in a byte somewhere in the memory. In order to display this value on the screen, it has to be converted to pixels, somehow. Usually the byte is first converted to a string. That could be "a" or "97", or something else. That is coded into the software.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic building block of electronic data is a bit. It can have only 2 values, 0 and 1. Other data structures are built from collection of bits, such as an 8-bit byte, or a 32-bit float.

When a collection of bits needs to be used to represent a character, a certain encoding is used to give lexical meaning to these bits, such as ASCII, UTF8 and others.

When you want to display character information to the screen, you use a graphical layer to draw pixels representing the "character" (collection of bits with matching encoding) to the screen.

Comment: Okay @Amit but, how my computer will know if this group 110000 is a 0 or the number 48?